# how to display a popup window in php codeigniter

Tags: php

This is the code for displaying pop up window and edit details in php using codeigniter framework.We wrote the corresponding code for displaying pop up window and edit individual details but it is not working..here we attach the view code..plz correct it.
    jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js">

```
         <div id="addLand" title="Land Details">
        <table width="87%" border="1">
        <?php
            $attr= array('name' => 'frmSave', 'id' => 'frmSave');
            echo form_open('#',$attr);
        ?>
           <input name="txtLandId" type="hidden" id="txtLandId" size="20"/>   
          <tr>
            <td width="57%">Name <span  class="errMsgMark">*</span></td>
            <td width="43%"><label>
              <input name="txt_lname" type="text" id="txt_lname" tabindex="1" size="20" maxlength="50"/>
            </label></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Location<span  class="errMsgMark">*</span></td>
            <td><input name="txt_location" type="text" id="txt_location" tabindex="5" size="20" maxlength="10"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div id="ERRmsg1"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="button" name="ButSave" value="Save" id="ButSave" class="buttonCSS1"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="ButCancel" value="Close" id="ButCancel" class="buttonCSS1" tabindex="9"/></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            echo form_close();
        ?>
        </table>
        </div>
<table width="100%" border="1" class="mGrid">
          <tr>
            <th width="6%"><div align="center">Sl.No</div></th>
            <th width="22%"><div align="center">Name</div></th>
            <th width="23%"><div align="center">Location</div></th>
            <th colspan="3"><input type="button" name="ButNew" value="New" id="ButNew" class="buttonCSS1"/></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
    <?php
                $str1='';
                $y=0;
                $i=0;
                //$LandM_Details=array();
                //print_r($LandM_Details);
                foreach($LandM_Details->result() as $row)
                {
                    $y=$i+1;  
                    $str1.= '<tr><td width="5%" height="23" >'.$y.'</td>';
                    $str1.= '<td width="25%" height="23">'.$row->land_name.'</td>';
                    $str1.= '<td width="15%" height="23" >'.$row->land_location.'</td>';
                    $str1.= '<td align=center><a href=# onclick=EditDetails('.$row->id.');>Edit</a></td>';
                    $i++;
                }
                echo $str1;
    ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            $('#addLand').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                resizable:false,
                width:'370px'
            });
$('#ButNew').click(function(){
                            //document.getElementByName('txt_lname').value='';
                            //document.getElementByName('txt_id').value=0;
                            //$('#txt_lname').val('');
                            //$('#txt_location').val('');
                            $('#addLand').dialog('open');
            });

        $('#ButSave').click(function(){           //Save land details........
                    var values = $("#frmSave").serialize();
                    alert(values);
                            $.ajax({
                               type: "POST",
                               url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/home/get_land_details",
                               data: values,
                               dataType: "json",
                               success: function(msg){
                                alert(msg.success);
                                    if(msg.success=="1")
                                    {
                                        $('#ERRmsg1').html(msg.val);
                                        $("#addLand").dialog('close');
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                         $("#ERRmsg1").html(msg.val);
                                    }
                                },
                               error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                               { 
                                     alert( jqXHR.responseText);
                               }
                            });

              });
              function EditDetails(v1)     //Edit Land details...........
                {       
                            document.getElementById('txtLandId').value=v1;
                            //document.getElementById('txt_location').value=v2;
                                var values = $("#frmSave").serialize();
                                alert(values);
                                $.ajax({
                                       type: "POST",
                                       url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/home/get_land_details",
                                       data: values,
                                       dataType: "json",
                                       success: function(msg){
                                       alert(msg.success);
                                            $('#txt_lname').val(msg.land_name);
                                            $('#txt_location').val(msg.land_location);
                                            //$('#addLand').dialog('open');                         
                                        },
                                       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                                        { 
                                             alert( jqXHR.responseText);
                                        }
                                    });

                            }
    });
    </script>         here
```

Comment: whats the problem you are facing i mean any error?

Comment: do you see any error message on firebug or developer tools window?

Comment: cannot display a pop up window,edit button is not working